# Manage/Change/Add user claims in azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have an instance of Azure B2C, we have a custom flow which allows users to sign up and sets some claims for that user.

We have an issue where we need to change some of the claims AFTER the user has been created, how do we manage this via the Azure portal? Can we?

We also have a requirement where we would like to assign users to security groups (or similar) in B2C but this doesnt seem possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this via the portal.

You could have a backend process that adds the claims via Graph API.

You could also add this to the sign-in process i.e. test if "ClaimsExist" and add them if not. Or maybe call a REST API in the flow to do this.

In terms of B2C groups, refer to [this](https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/).

Comment: Thats a bit of a pain. The issue we have is that we have a claim that we set at sign up, but that needs to change after a period of time. Ill look for other options now.

Comment: Have a look at this sample - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days That forces the password to change after 90 days. So you could do a similar thing to update the claim after x days.